# Insert input data into the body of an email phpmailer

Tags: php, forms, phpmailer

I have a form consisting of many inputs but the division is: referent | email | id | dataplate | energy label. If I do a var_dump I can actually see what I write. The problem I have is when I have to insert these values inside the body of the email. The most I can get is just the last number I enter in the form but all the others are missing.

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["quantitad_form"]); $i++) {
    
    $referente = $_POST["referente"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $id_form = $_POST["id_form"][$i];
    $quantitad_form = $_POST["quantitad_form"][$i];
    $quantitae_form = $_POST["quantitae_form"][$i];
}
```

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'mysmtp';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'myemail';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'mypassword';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                           
    $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('emailfrom');
    $mail->addAddress($_POST['email']);     // Add a recipient



    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'ciao';
     $mail->Body    = "message";//start of body

foreach ($quantitad_form as &$value) {
    $mail->Body    = $value;
}

    $mail->send();
    header('Location: http://www.example.net/contact.php');
    exit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

I expect to receive an email with all the fields in the form, thank you all for any suggestions or help.

Answer (score 1):

in the `foreach` loop you are overwriting the Body instead of appending to it..
try:

```
foreach ($quantitad_form as &$value) {
    $mail->Body    .= $value;
}
```

But you also do not store all the fields from the form within $quantitad_form as an array... so you need to fix that as well

Comment: I'm really confused, can you explain more? Thank you

Comment: in your script you use `=` in the foreach, which will everytime set the Body to the last $value ... if you instead use `.=` this will APPEND each $value to the previous VALUE of `$mail->Body`.. its like: `$mail->Body = $mail->Body . $value;` . This way you APPEND the `$values` instead of deleting the old and assigning the latest..

Comment: is there a system to include all the input fields divided into a table in the body? thanks for the explanation

Comment: Yes, you’ll need to write code to generate HTML table tags.

Comment: You again ask fr a ready solution, without showing your work to even attempt to do this... It is very easy to create Key = Value list... (you do not even need a table), but did you even search or try to create this? there are literally Thousands of tutorials online on how to accomplish this..

Comment: @Ron I tried to enter the code with the . but I don't get anything in the body in the email.
As far as entering multiple values I had thought of something like this but that doesn't work

`foreach ($quantitad_form as $key => $datarequest) 
{
    $mail->Body    .= $datarequest . '; ' . $id_form . '; ' . $quantitae_form . PHP_EOL;
}`

Comment: Edit your question and add the HTML form, so we can see how you add your form values.. Usually you need `foreach($_POST as $k=>$v){ $mail->Body .= "$k = $v" . PHP_EOL; }`. Also have you debugged if your $_POST actually contains all the form data you need before you try to email it? You can first structure the output from your $_POST and make sure that is what you expect as an output, before you even try to use the Mailer...